# "network discovery is turned off" and won't turn on

Tags: windows, windows-10, network-discovery

I have done quite a bit of research on this but every tutorial that I managed to find are saying the same thing.
What you need to do:

- Enable DNS Client Service
- Enable UPnP Device Host Service
- Enable Function Discovery Resource Publication Service
- Enable SSDP Discovery Service

and lastly where my problem is...

- Allow Network Discovery through your firewall

Allow Network Discovery through your firewall:

[image]

Which in my case is not found in this list.

Comment: Is your network connection (not firewall) set for Private? It does not seem so. It seems to be set for Public which prevents Network Discovery.

Comment: it is private

[image](https://imgur.com/UUEBNXo)

Comment: Try running DISM / SFC   (1) Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator.
(2) DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /StartComponentCleanup
(3) DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-Image /Restorehealth
(4) SFC /SCANNOW
(5) Restart when all the above is complete and test.     Maybe reset Firewall to defaults first.